# NodeJS - Recovering from a try-catch of a thrown error, in-mid Promises-Chain (asynchrous - "second path")

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, request, try-catch

Recently I have been struggling with a problem that rose up because of NodeJS's asynchronous nature.
I have a situation where I try to issue a `request` to one server, and if it does not work (because of a `timeout` for example), I "replace" it - by issuing a `request` to another server to supply me the data, and continue the code execution.
Right now, what actually happens is that once the `catch` method is being called, I am not sure how to "Go back" to the same place it stopped at, and continue the `.then` (Promise) chain.
Of course I can write code after the .catch and watch it being executed, but 2 things would probably happen:
1. This code will run asynchronously "without waiting".
2. I'll have to replicate large chunks of code, over and over, while nesting them inside each other, using promises and catch blocks, which will elevate the "Promises-chaining-hell", and which is obviously, or probably, not the correct way to achieve.

A short description of what I am trying to achieve:

```
const options1 = {
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 1500,
    uri: 'https://www.example.com/'
}

const options2 = {
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 1500,
    uri: 'https://www.example.com/'
}

const options3 = {
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 1500,
    uri: 'https://www.example.com/'
}


    //Code before

    request(options1)
        .then(function (response) {
            //Server 1 is working - execute what's inside .then
            request(options3)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //Got the data from server 1 or 2, doesn't matter, now get the required data from server 3

                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    //Timeout has been thrown, show an error and continue
                    console.log('Server 3 error occured, continuing.');
                });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //Timeout has been thrown, show an error and continue
            request(options2)
            .then(function (response) {


            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //Server 2 doesn't work either, abord and notify the user
                console.log('Server 2 error occured, continuing.');
            });
              console.log('Server 1 error occured, continuing.');
        });
```

Should I use an outside function, in-order to define those "recovery routes"?
Thank you.

Comment: The outer catch won't execute as the error is handled by inner catch. Just try to rethrow the error inside inner catch then it will be handled by the next catch it will encounter.

Comment: Always `return` any promises created in your `then` callbacks. The outer promise will resolve with the callback result. This works for `catch` equally.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a common function for what happens when the 1st / 2nd request succeeds. This function can be called in both the cases without code duplication.

```
request(options1)
    .then(function (response) {
        //Server 1 is working - execute what's inside .then
        return request3(response);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //Timeout has been thrown, show an error and continue
        return request(options2)
        .then(function (response) {
            return request3(response);
        });
    });

function request3() {
    // return a promise here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer tbking.
But let's say I have many requests, around 14, all should be nested in function as request3, with try-catch?

Comment: All the requests can be put in function `request3`. And no try-catch is needed when dealing with promises. All uncaught exceptions will be caught at the nearest `catch` block. PS: If you want this retry mechanism for each of those 14 requests, you can make a generic `requestN` function which takes n and continue to make remaining requests i.e. 14-n

Answer (score 0):

You just return a promise to `then(){}` scope, and rest is taken care by the promises. So, as you yourself said, you can attach a "then" block after the catch, and write post execution code their, but you need to return a promise to the parent, which takes care of the chaining and consecutive calling of attached callbacks.

Something like this:

```
//Code before

request(options1)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Success 1")
        //Server 1 is working - execute what's inside .then
       return request(options3)
            .then(function (response) {
                //Got the data from server 1 or 2, doesn't matter, now get the required data from server 3
                console.log("Success 3")
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //Timeout has been thrown, show an error and continue
                console.log('Server 3 error occured, continuing.');
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Failed 1")
        //Timeout has been thrown, show an error and continue
        return request(options2)
        .then(function (response) {

            console.log("Success 2")

        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Failed 1")
            //Server 2 doesn't work either, abord and notify the user
            console.log('Server 2 error occured, continuing.');
        });
    })
    .then( ()=>{
        console.log("Post execution")

    } )
```

Hope it helps.

You can validate by throwing an error inside then block along with a timeout, and force the catch block to execute.